variable with hyphen in bash script
db1="community-service-data"
db2="ecomm-data-test"

drop_db="DROP DATABASE ${db1}"
sudo -u postgres -S /bin/bash -c "psql -U postgres -d postgres -c \"${drop_db}\""
drop_db="DROP DATABASE \"ecomm-data-test\";"
sudo -u postgres -S /bin/bash -c "psql -U postgres -d postgres -c \"${drop_db}\""


error
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: DROP DATABASE community-service-data
                               ^

I have db names with hyphen in them. I am dropping these databases from a bash script. It keeps complaining about the '-' in the variable. I tried quoting but it doesn't work.
I even tried drop_db="DROP DATABASE \"${db1}\"" If I do in quotes in the psql command line directly then it works.
how can I do it correctly.
Thanks
update:
drop_db=(DROP DATABASE "${db1}") 

error:
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: DROP
            ^


What's the actual error message

Please also include the command that works

psql# DROP DATABASE "community-service-data";   this one works!!!

@ChrisDavies ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-" LINE 1: DROP DATABASE community-service-data

Please add all relevant information to the question body. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. The error seems to be from postgres, by the way, not the shell. do you perhaps need to do some special quoting in postgres, like \my_table``?

If not, can you try drop_db=(DROP DATABASE "${db1}") and then sudo -u postgres -S /bin/bash -c "psql -U postgres -d postgres -c '${drop_db[@]}'", does that work?

@terdon that can't work; the drop_db[@] will get expanded in the outermost shell context

@ChrisDavies yes, so it should become 'DROP' 'DATABASE' 'community-service-data' and not 'DROP DATABASE community-service-data', right? Which is what we likely need here, I thought.

@CodeWeed: Why are you calling bash to call psql instead of calling psql directly?  Feels like some quoting is likely being eaten up in this layering.

@bxm presumably this is part of a larger script that needs to do various things, including one psql command. This is quite common, after all.

Good question @bxm

@terdon drop_db=(DROP DATABASE "${db1}") does not work either. error ERROR:  syntax error at end of input.
@ChrisDavies I think that seems to be the problem but not sure how can I escape the string to interpret it as a single string ?
@bxm these instructions are part of a larger bash script.

@terdon, that'll turn into the equivalent of sudo ... bash -c "psql -U postgres -d postgres -c 'DROP" "DATABASE" "community-service-data'", i.e. it'll split the string that was supposed to be given as argument to -c.

right, right, and that's what Chris was getting at. You're right, @ilkkachu, I'm thinking of shell tokenization but it is psql that's relevant here.

The complexity here is that Postgres requires the database name to be in double quotes. You're also calling an extra layer of shell. Try this instead:
db1="community-service-data"
db2="ecomm-data-test"

drop_db="DROP DATABASE \"$db1\""

then
sudo -u postgres -S psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "$drop_db"

or
sudo -u postgres -S psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "DROP DATABASE \"$db2\""

You say that the fragment is part of a larger script. If a large part of the script is supposed to be run under sudo -u postgres then create a separate function in your script that's called only if a flag is provided, and then catch that to run it alone. For example, under sudo -u postgres /path/to/my/script -P, where -P is the flag that calls your function

The first one worked thank you. I think it was the way I call the bash and sending the command in two layers. first to bash =>  psql => command string.

There's no need for sudo or bash here. postgresql comes with a standalone dropdb executable to remove databases, and more advanced shells like zsh can switch users and do stuff by themselves:
#! /bin/zsh -
for db (community-service-data ecomm-data-test) USERNAME=postgres dropdb $db

dropdb will construct the right SQL command whatever characters the db name contains¹.
Just enclosing the value inside " doesn't work for arbitrary values. Obviously, it doesn't work for values containing ", but it could also fail upon encoding clashes.
If using psql, it's better to pass values via psql variables:
db='--my "cool" db--'
USERNAME=postgres dropdb -- "$db"

Can also be written (still in zsh):
db='--my "cool" db--'
USERNAME=postgres psql -v db=$db <<< 'drop database :"db"'


¹ Though you have to make sure it's encoded using the same charset as used by dropdb; see the PGCLIENTENCODING variable to change it if need be.
